# Recreating Heffernan-Tawn Fig. 6 in R: samples from multivariate extreme value distribution

Tags: extreme-value, multivariate-distribution

I am trying to recreate Figure 6 from Heffernan-Tawn (2004) *[A conditional approach for multivariate extreme values](https://www.d.umn.edu/%7Eyqi/mydownload/heffemantawn.pdf)* using the same datasets as used in the paper. The original time series data of air pollutants is available from [here](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/). Taking just winter samples of NO and NO$_2$ (Fig. 6 (a)) as examples and referring to them with subscripts 1 and 2, respectively, and simplifying some of the notation, here is the general procedure:

As far as I understand, the paper uses the following steps to create Figure 6:

1. Independently transform the original samples $X_1,X_2$ to Gumbel margins $t_1(X_1), t_2(X_2)=Y_1,Y_2$ by fitting a generalised Pareto distribution to samples exceeding the 70% quantile of each vector.
2. Fit the conditional dependence model of $Y_2 | Y_1 = y_1 \geq u_{Y_1}$ for some chosen threshold $u_{Y_1}$. The dependence structure is (generally) given by $$Y_2 = ay_1 + y_1^bZ,$$ $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \sigma_0)$, where $(a,b,\mu_0,\sigma_0)$. Then $Y_2$ has a conditional distribution of $ \mathcal{N} (\mu(y_1), \sigma(y_1))$. Where $$ \mu(y_1) = ay_1 + y_1^b\mu_0 \\ \sigma(y_1) = y_1^{b}\sigma_0.$$ This is optimised for $(a,b, \mu_0, \sigma_0)$ by maximising the Gaussian log-likelihood function
   $$Q= \sum_{k \in S} \log(\sigma(y_1^{(k)}) + \frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{y_2^{(k)} - \mu(y_1^{(k)})}{\sigma(y_1^{(k)})}\right]^2$$
   where $S$ is the set of indices for which $y_1 \geq u_{Y_1}.$
3. To generate new extreme samples: sample $N$ new extreme $Y_1^*$ from a standard Gumbel distribution, exceeding a chosen threshold $v_{Y_1}$. Then sample $N$ samples from $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \sigma_0)$ and use the fitted $(a,b)$ to generate samples of $Y_2$ as in step 2.
4. Transform $Y_1, Y_2$ back to $X_1,X_2$ using $t_i^{-1}(Y_i)$ and plot the scatterplot. I am defining the inverse transform for $Y > u_{Y} =-\log(-\log(\tilde{F}(u_{X}))$ as
   $$
   X_1 = u_{X_1} + \frac{\beta}{\xi}
   \left[
   \left(
   \frac{1 - \text{e}^{-\text{e}^{-Y_1}}}{1-\tilde{F}(u_{X_1})} - 1
   \right)^{-\xi}
   \right]
   $$
   and otherwise just the quantile function of the empirical CDF. I think I should also be able to use the quantile function of the fitted generalised Pareto distribution for $\log(Y > u_{Y}$ but the results R function `POT::qgpd` gave me looked quite strange.

Using R, this is my procedure.

1. Transform the $X_1,X_2$ to Gumbel margins according to Equations $(1.3)$ and $(1.4)$ in the paper using the following code. A threshold $\tilde F(u_x) =0.7$ is used in the paper. I obtain $\beta$ and $\xi$ from the function `POT::fitgpd(x, threshold=quantile(x, 0.7))`.

```
gumbel_transform <- function(x, quant, xi, beta){
  F.x <- ecdf(x)
  u.x <- quantile(F.x, quant)
  F.hat.x <- sapply(x, F.marginal, u.x=u.x, F.x=F.x, xi=xi, beta=beta)
  return(list("Y"=-log(-log(F.hat.x)), "F"=F.x))
}

F.marginal <- function(x, u.x, F.x, xi, beta){
  if(x <= u.x){
    return(F.x(x))
  }
  else{
    pareto.tail <- max(1 + xi * (x - u.x) / beta, 0)^(-1 / xi)
    return(1 - (1 - F.x(u.x)) * pareto.tail)
  }
}
NO.fit <- POT::fitgpd(winter$NO, quantile(winter$NO, .7))
NO.transform <- gumbel_transform <- function(winter$NO, .7, xi=fit$fitted.values[1], beta=fit$$fitted.values[1])
```

2. Fit $Y_2$ conditional on $Y_1 > t_1(u_{X_1})$ by finding the optimal set $(a,b,\mu_0,\sigma_0)$ and defining the objective function $Q$ and its gradient as follows

```
Q <- function (par, data, conditions)
{ # modified from library tsxtreme (changed par limits)
  # (5.2) in Heffernan-Tawn (2004)
  if (par[4] <= 0) {
    return(Inf)
  }
  if (conditions) {
    if (!conditions.verify(par[1], par[2], 0, data = data) || 
        !conditions.verify(par[1], par[2], 1, data = data)) {
      return(Inf)
    }
  }
  else {
    if (par[1] < 0 || par[1] > 1 || par[2] >= 1) {
      return(Inf)
    }
  }
  
  sigma <- par[4] * data[, 1]^(2 * par[2])
  
  if(par[1]==0 & par[2] < 0){
    mu = par[5] + par[6] * log(data[, 1]) + par[3] * data[, 1]^par[2]
  } else{
    mu <- par[1] * data[, 1] + par[3] * data[, 1]^par[2]
  }
  return(sum(log(sigma) + (data[, 2] - mu)^2/sigma))
}

dQ <- function (par, data, conditions) 
{ # modified from tsxtreme
  sig <- par[4] * data[, 1]^(2 * par[2])
  mu <- par[1] * data[, 1] + par[3] * data[, 1]^par[2]
  cen <- data[, 2] - mu
  d.a <- -2 * sum(cen * data[, 1]/sig)
  d.b <- 2 * sum(log(data[, 1]) * (1 - cen * (par[3] * data[, 1]^par[2] + cen)/sig))
  d.m <- -2 * sum(cen/(data[, 1]^(par[2]) * par[4]))
  d.s <- sum((1 - cen^2/sig)/par[4])
  return(c(d.a, d.b, d.m, d.s))
}
```

and fit for $(a,b,\mu_0,\sigma_0)$

```
a <- runif(1, -1, 1)
b <- runif(1, 0, 1)
fit <- optim(par=c(a, b, 0, 1), fn=Q, gr=dQ, conditions=FALSE,
                 data=c(Y$NO, Y$NO2), hessian=TRUE, method="BFGS")
```

3. Simulate extreme samples $Y_1^*$ from $Y_{\text{NO}}$, exceeding the 99% quantile by sampling uniformly from $q\in[0.99, 1)$ and applying the Gumbel quantile function $y = -\log(-\log(q))$ (see [other Stack question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/616950/gumbel-distribution-conditional-on-exceeding-a-threshold)).
4. Simulate the same number of samples from $\mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \sigma_0)$ and transform them using the fitted $(a,b)$ to obtain $Y_2^*$.
5. Inverse-transform these back to $X_1^*, X_2^*$ using the inverse of (1.3) and (1.4)

```
# Inverse Gumbel transforms
inv.gumbel <- function(y, q, transform, fit){
  u <- quantile(transform$F, q)
  x <- sapply(y, inv.gumbel.inner, u=u, q=q, transform=transform, fit=fit)
}

inv.gumbel.inner <- function(y, u, q, transform, fit){
  if(y <= -log(-log(q))){
    return(quantile(fit$F, exp(-exp(-y))))
  }else{
inner <- ((1- transform$F(u)) / (1 - exp(-exp(-y))))^fit$shape
outer <- (fit$scale / fit$shape) * (inner - 1) + u
return(outer)
#return(POT::qgpd(exp(-exp(-y)), loc=u, scale=fit$scale, shape=fit$shape))
  }
}
X.sample$NO <- inv.gumbel(Y.sample$NO, q=q.u, transform=NO.transform, fit=NO.fit)
```

Here is my Fig. 6 (a). As you can see the NO2 values being simulated are all beneath the equal marginal quantile and it's not right.

[image: My simulation]

Here is how it should look
[image: Heffernan-Tawn]